# Where do I find free PCB designer programs?

Tags: gratis

I'm a huge video game fan, and I'm looking to recreate the TurboGrafX myself, from gate level. My issue is that I can't find a free PCB program online, anywhere. Is there something professional I can get a hold of without selling my sole to the devil?

Comment: [KiCad.](http://kicad-pcb.org/)  The google-fu is weak with this one.

Comment: Sell your foot to the devil? :P Wrong "soul". Anyways, yes I recommend KiCAD, FreePCB, DesignSpark PCB, and there's more but a lot to list. If you want to find more, simply type in, "Open source PCB design software" or "Free PCB design software" on Google. There's plenty out there. I don't know how you're going to create the TurboGrafX console considering that they have particular ROM code that is more than likely not accessible on the internet... and that goes for the schematic as well.

Comment: @KingDuken - maybe he's wanting to sell his [sole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sole_(fish)) ... ?

Comment: Wow, -gate- level, that is going at it old school, for freeware on -that- aspect, I think Vivado and Quartus II are free.

Comment: My goal is to recreate it based on documentation on the web, so that I can re implement the instruction set. My second goal is to get experienced with hardware design.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is contradictory. A PCB is a circuit board. A "gate level" design is the internals of a microchip. The software used to design these two things is completely different.

For PCB design, [Kicad](http://kicad-pcb.org/) is a highly capable free tool.

A "gate-level" design is a bit unclear, but would probably refer to either an FPGA or VLSI design. Free software for these workflows is largely nonexistent -- [Project Icestorm](http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/) has some tools targeting Lattice iCE40 FPGAs, but these parts are rather small and are unlikely to support the system you are targeting.

Comment: what's the term for gate-level design?

Comment: "Gate-level design" is an ambiguous term, and is generally not used in the industry.

Comment: why? I would think it would be pretty common...

Comment: also, how did you get 101 rep without any questions or answers?

Comment: @JackKasbrack Because if you're here long enough on StackExchange, you get 100 free points to any website... Hover over my name. See? Now I have 101 points too. But I've been using the entire StackExchange website for a few years.

Comment: k, cool. just curious. In any event, if gate-level design is so obscure, then how do companies like Intel and nVidia design their chips?

Comment: @JackKasbrack It’s not “obscure”; it’s simply an ambiguous term.

Comment: so is gate-level design common or not? if not, why not?

Comment: As I have said repeatedly, **"gate-level design" is an ambiguous term.** It's not clear what you are trying to refer to.

Comment: oh, my bad. didn't completely know what ambiguous meant. I apologize for the stupid comments. anyway, what are the differences between some of the classifications of "gate-level design"?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I didn't realize this got transferred from the EE side, so (where I could comment):
For a brief history/background, google "gate level synthesis",
you should get a reference to this document from MIT a few hits down (it's a history/background/intro)
[l05_synthesis.pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-884-complex-digital-systems-spring-2005/resources/l05_synthesis/)
I don't' know if this link will work for you hence the above refs:

[MIT Lecture Notes 6.884 on *Complex Digital Systems*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-884-complex-digital-systems-spring-2005/pages/lecture-notes/)